# Is it possible to install a composer package without updating the composer.json

Tags: composer-php

I want to install a composer package, but I only want it in my environment for developing purposes, I don't want other developers to install it or even see that I have it.

What is the equivalent of `npm install pack/age` without the `--save` in composer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is an exact Composer equivalent to `npm install` without `--save`.

One way to get a similar result is to use [Composer's `global` command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global) to install the package globally for your user:

```
composer global require some/package
```

This is much like `npm install -g` if you've configured NPM to put such modules in your home directory instead of in a shared location. Binaries will then be available in your global [vendor binaries](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md) directory, which on my machine is `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/`.

Another option would be to simply use `composer require` in your project directory and then revert any changes to `composer.json` and `composer.lock` with whatever version control system you use. The downside of this is that the newly installed packages won't be included in your [autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) the next time it gets generated.